# Cointegration/GPH test on time series data

Tags: r, time-series

I am quite new to R and statistics. I want to test two time series with the GPH test for cointegration. For this I use the package `LongMemoryTS` and the function gph(): `gph(X, m, l = 1)`. As output I get the value for the parameter d, but I don't know how to determine the t-value or how to generate it.

Here a link to the function in the package: https://rdrr.io/cran/LongMemoryTS/man/gph.html

Here my first try as a code snippet:

```
lr.reg.IP_AT_EN <- lm(IP_AT~IP_DE)
error.IP_AT_EN <- residuals(lr.reg.IP_AT_DE)
T <- length(error.IP_AT_EN)
d.IP_AT_DE <- gph(X=error.IP_AT_DE, m=T^0.4)
```

Thanks a lot in advance for the help!

Comment: Could you add some simple data to it to make it easier for people to reproduce?

Answer (score 0):

For obtaining critical values, it seems like bootstrapping is a good approach, see here http://repec.org/sce2004/up.4249.1077649371.pdf.
There's also the approach of using the theoretical error variance (see page 3 in the paper). I'm not entirely sure if this is correct, but you would at least obtain a statistic with this code:

```
library(xts)
library(LongMemoryTS)

set.seed(123)
# generate some data
dat_ts <- xts(matrix(rnorm(200), ncol = 2), order.by = seq.Date(Sys.Date()-100, length.out = 100, by = 'days'))
              
reg1 <- lm(dat_ts[, 1]~dat_ts[, 2])
error_reg1 <- residuals(reg1)
nT <- length(error_reg1) # bad idea to name it T!

res1 <- gph(X=error_reg1, m=nT^0.4)
res1 

t_stat <- (res1-0)/((pi^2)/6)^0.5
p_value <- pt(q = t_stat, df = 1, lower.tail = TRUE)
p_value
[1] 0.3831716
```